# C# string being truncated in Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, firefox

I have an ASPX app that saves some HTML into to a PDF.

My issue is when building the filename string.

Here is my code.

```
        string ext = ".pdf";
        string custname = custnamehidden.Value.ToString();
        var invnumber = invnumberhidden.Value.ToString();

            doc.Save(Response, false, "INV-" + invnumber + custname + ext);
```

If I run the code in EDGE, the filename looks like "INV-15452Test School.pdf", which is correct

My issue is when I try the same thing in Firefox, the string stops at the first space "INV-15452Test"

Any help greatly apprecitaed

Comment: `var fileName = @"INV-1542Test School.pdf"` or try string interpolation. Not "INV-" + invnumber + ...

Answer (score 0):

Try [URL-encoding your filename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode?view=netframework-4.8) so that the space doesn't trip things up:

```
var filename = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("INV-" + invnumber + custname + ext);
doc.Save(Response, false, filename);
```